# How to @everywhere include(iter) from a for loop

Tags: julia

say I have a function like this

```
function paths(loc)
    if loc[end] == "/"
       loc = loc[1:end-1]    
    end
    [string(loc, script) for script in 
     ["/s1.jl", "/s2.jl", "/s3.jl"]]
end
```

and I want do this:

```
for p in paths("/some/path")
    @everywhere include(p)
end
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: p not defined
eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
eval_ew_expr at ./distributed/macros.jl:116 [inlined]
(::Base.Distributed.##135#136{Base.Distributed.#eval_ew_expr,Tuple{Expr},Array{Any,1}})() at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:314
run_work_thunk(::Base.Distributed.##135#136{Base.Distributed.#eval_ew_expr,Tuple{Expr},Array{Any,1}}, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:56
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
(::##189#191)() at ./distributed/macros.jl:102
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:340
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
(::##189#191)() at ./distributed/macros.jl:102
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end() at ./task.jl:287
 [2] macro expansion at ./distributed/macros.jl:112 [inlined]
 [3] macro expansion at ./REPL[33]:2 [inlined]
 [4] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

The question is, if this is possible, how do I get this to work?

Comment: Replace `@everywhere include(p)` with `@everywhere include($p)`. The `$` is interpolation, which substitutes the `p` symbol with its value in the expression parameter to `@everywhere`.

Comment: Hey @DanGetz, you can post the same as the answer :-) that way it wont be visible in questions with no answers.

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal Posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@everywhere include(p)` with `@everywhere include($p)`. The `$` is interpolation, which substitutes the `p` symbol with its value in the expression parameter to `@everywhere`.